# Cannot resolve symbol 'animSlide'

Tags: java, android

I really don't understand why I have this error.

```java
package com.example.paul_2.a18martie;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout ll;
    TextView tv;
    ImageView imag1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ioi);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aatrox);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,120);
        params.leftMargin = 50;
        params.topMargin = 60;
        rl.addView(iv, params);

        animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.slide);
        iv.startAnimation(animSlide);
```

Can someone tell me why animSlide give's me the error Cannot resolve symbol 'animSlide'.
I can let you the slide.xml file but I think isn't the problem...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

I am sorry if I am terribly wrong with something, but I am very new on all of this.

Comment: It appears that your code example is cut short. I suspect that you have more code, but it isn't relevant to the question, which is perfectly fine, preferable even. You should still add the closing braces for the `onCreate()` method and `MainActivity` class so that your code is complete.

Comment: In my code it are closed, but after the code I putted here, I have a lot of comments and after them I have the closing braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you must declare all variables. The compiler is complaining because you use a variable named `animSlide` without declaring it.

Comment: And how should I declare it? I mean, what type has to be?

Comment: @PaulAndrei You should look at the documentation for `loadAnimation()` which tells you the return type. Since you are assigning the return value to `animSlide`, the types must be compatible. For now I would just use the exact same type. When you learn about polymorphism, you will find that the return type and the variable don't have to be the exact same type, but there are still some rules to follow which is why I said "compatible".

Comment: I find it into the documentation. Thank you!